# Focus of TextBox is always set to start Whenever a div in updatePanel is scrolled to bottom by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, textbox, focus

This is the javascript function which is called every 5 second(that code not shown) and this code keeps the scrollbar to the bottom of div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ScrollToBottom(id) {
        var ctl = $get(id);
        ctl.scrollTop = ctl.scrollHeight;


    }

</script>
```

On page load

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,
                                    this.GetType(),
                                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                    ";ScrollToBottom('"
                                        + MyDiv.ClientID
                                        + "');",
                                    true);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Message.Focus();
        }
```

But my problem is that every time the focus of TextBox is set to the beginning while I m Writing something in the TextBox. I want the focus of the cursor not troubled by that javascript function which brings div scroll to bottom

This is how click is called at every 5 seconds so that new data inside updatel can be added

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       setInterval(function () {
           document.getElementById("btnExitChatRoom").click();
       }, 5000);



</script>
```

Comment: I just can't understand *what* is setting the focus on that interval. `TextBox1.focus();` should be called just once. Maybe you can show your interval function.

Comment: There is a button click event that is called always after 5 second

Comment: But if that button is reloading the page then `TextBox1.focus();` will be called everytime, do you agree ? Did your page_load is called more than once?

Comment: Yes I agree and I have kept Message.focus() inside !page.isPostBack, But result is same

Comment: One more Thing, My div is inside updatePanel

Comment: I have edited My question and at last How click is called at every 5 second has been shown

Comment: Dude, whatever is affecting the input focus is not shown on your post. Everything seems to be ok. Probably something(that you not showing) is causing that behaviour.